# How to interpret BLE battery level response

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I am using react-native-ble-plx library to fetch battery level from the device but I am unable to interpret the data fetched.

I am getting "MA==" as value after reading characteristic:

[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: You need to base64 decode that value -- looks like it decodes to `0`. In my case I'd get values like `*`, for which you would additionally call `charCodeAt` like `'*'.charCodeAt(0)`, which gives the right value (in this example 42).